# mockito: spy on iBatis queryForObject and modify parameter map

Tags: jakarta-ee, ibatis, mockito

I am using iBatis 2.2 and wanted to mock this call to queryForObject

```
this.queryForObject("stored_proc_name", paramMap);
```

The paramMap is build inside a method and holds the input parameters and will also hold an **errorCode** and an **errorMessage** after the proc invocation (output parameters to the proc). I would like to set those two values into the paramMap when the line gets called. 
 I am using a "spy" on my dao object and intercept when above line is invoked. I tried doing the following but it doesn't work since I am not actually capturing the result object in the java code but rely on the modified paramMap..

```
doReturn(paramMap).when(daoSpy).queryForObject(eq("stored_proc_name"), anyMap());
```

Does anybody know if it's possible to modify that paramMap when the queryForObject call is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You should use an `Answer` object, with a method that adds the required value to the map that's passed in.  It might look something like this.

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Map<String,Object>>(){
   @Override
   public Map<String,Object> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
      Map<String,Object> params = (Map<String,Object>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
      params.put("errorCode", 55);
      params.put("errorMessage", "Your message here");
      return params;
   }}).when(daoSpy).queryForObject(
      eq("stored_proc_name"), anyMapOf(String.class, Object.class));
```

For more information, http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs